# Sets and relations - the set $A\cup ( B \times C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A = \{a_4,a_7,a_5,a_1\},\; B = \{a_1,a_4\},\; C = \{a_8, a_7\}$

There is 3 questions:

Firstly: The cartesian product $A \times B$ which I answered: $$\{[a_4,a_1],[a_4,a_4],[a_7,a_1],[a_7,a_4],[a_5,a_1],[a_5,a_4],[a_1,a_1],[a_1,a_4]\}$$ (I'm assuming this is correct)

The next question:

the set $A\cup  ( B \times C)$

and the third:

the set $(A \cup B) \times C$

I'm very stuck on 2 and 3 even after copious YouTube videos and Googling.

Thanks

Comment: Boy,your prof likes to make you work,huh,Liam?

Comment: Lol, yes. Unfortunately I've missed the last month and can't get access to any of the notes from the classes, so just doing what I can. All good fun :)

Comment: Uh-what's * mean? Is this a Cartesian product or......? I've never seen that notation with sets before.

Comment: This is why I can't find anything I'm sure. I'm assuming it's Cartesian product going by the first question, perhaps I should edit it back to the way it was.

Comment: Yes,I think that would be wise because that's the standard notation for it.You're confusing me,dude. And I've chatted about set theory with Saul Kripke,so that's not easy to do......lol

Comment: And get yourself a copy of this book-I wish I'd had it when I studied set theory. http://www.amazon.com/Notes-Theory-Undergraduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/038728723X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1426133675&sr=8-1&keywords=notes+on+set+theory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $A\cup (B \times C)$, we first need to construct  $B \times C$:

$B \times C = \{ (a_1,a_8), (a_4,a_8),(a_1,a_7),(a_4,a_7)\}$

Now by definition,  $A\cup (B \times C)$ is the set of all elements that are in $A$, in $B \times C$ or both. Since the elements of $B \times C$ are ordered pairs and the elements of $A$ are single elements, clearly the sets have to be disjoint. So the union is simply the elements of $A$ and the elements of $B \times C$!

$A\cup (B \times C) = \{a_4,a_7,a_5,a_1,(a_1,a_8), (a_4,a_8),(a_1,a_7),(a_4,a_7)\}$

This is $A\cup (B \times C)$. Now the exact same logic used to solve the second problem can be used to solve the third. So go ahead and do it yourself.

Comment: Awesome, thanks :) I will definitely be getting that book.

Comment: 2 other great books, are Patrick Suppes'classic AXIOMATIC SET THEORY and Paul Halmos' NAIVE SET THEORY. Halmos'book taught basic set theory to an entire generation of mathematicians and it's just been reissued in a nice cheap paperback. Suppes is also a classic and it's more detailed then Halmos, but it relies much more on mathematical logic. Still,it's a great read and also available cheap through Dover!

Comment: Nice, I will check them out. Thanks :)